# How to create a binary file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, binaryfiles

I want to create a binary file in python so that will be according to following pattern:

```
4 bytes - zeros
16 bytes - this number 1010101010101010
```

How can I do it in python?

I tried to do it in the following way, but i don't sure that it's correct:

```
f = open('file', 'w+b')

res = struct.pack(">l", 0000)
f.write(res)
```

I tried to do it with struct.pack like you can see above, but while i print the content of the file - i get empty file.. and i don't understand why i don't see there the expected content.

in addition, how can i write the 16 bytes? i don't see appropriate Format for size of 16 bytes (regarding "struct" in python).

Comment: If you're not sure if your code is correct or not, well, execute it

Comment: `f.write(res)` - you cannot write a number this way. Convert it to bytes first `res.to_bytes` or use the struct module to produce the whole thing at once.

Comment: @Cid what you say is true, but i asking here: is this the right way to do it? And regarding testing the output, how can I know how the resulting binary file is composed (to test it)?

Comment: @gog I trying to do that: `res=1234; f.write(res.to_bytes)` but i get this error: `'int' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'`

Comment: Was was wrong with the output file when you ran this code?

Comment: @user20007266: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=to_bytes#int.to_bytes

Comment: @OldBill see my question now (after i edited it)

Comment: @user20007266 there are plenty of tool to open binary files, such as Hex Workshop and such

Comment: @user20007266 The current code in your question works perfectly fine. It will create a file containing `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'`. This can easily be verified with `r = open(file, 'rb').read(); print(repr(r), res == r)`. If you want more precise control, use [int.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#int.to_bytes) and [int.from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#int.from_bytes) - e.g. `file.write(num.to_bytes(16, 'big'))` ... `int.from_bytes(file.read(16), 'big')`.

Answer (score -1):

If you not sure, use

```py
print(open("file", "rb").read())
```

to check

Comment: How can i check it by the code you answered here? it give me binary output. so how can i know that the data that i want is really written there like that i want (according to the pattern that i writed in my question)

Comment: Only you know what you need, it depends on your needs, do you want to store the integer 12345678 in 8 bytes? If so maybe you need `struct.pack(">q", 12345678)`, please refer to the python documentation for the `struct` module.

Comment: and how i will write it to the file?

Comment: I tried to do it like you said, with `struct.pack` in this way: `res=struct.pack(">l", 1024); f.write(res)` but while i print the content of the file - i get empty file..

Comment: `struct.pack` return the type `bytes`, so just `f.write` the ` struct.pack` return value.

Comment: Did you call close after writing in?

Comment: yes. why did you ask?

Comment: ```import os
import struct
f = open('file', 'w+b')
res = struct.pack(">l", 1024)
f.write(res)
f.close()

print(open("file", "rb").read())
```
It cant be empty

Comment: what you see while you do it? i don't see letters or numbers in the output..